# Remove a child that does not have a specific class

Tags: jquery

I have this html:

```
<div class="post-content">
    I have something to give away for free. Call
    <span class="togglers">
        <a class="toggler selected" href="#" title="change" style="display: inline;">me</a>
        <span class="divider" style="display: inline;">|</span>
        <a class="toggler" href="#" title="change" style="display: inline;">us</a>
    </span> 
    today and
    <span class="togglers">
        <a class="toggler" href="#" title="change" style="display: inline;">I'll</a>
        <span class="divider" style="display: inline;">|</span>
        <a class="toggler" href="#" title="change" style="display: inline;">we'll</a>
    </span>
    hand deliver it to your doorstep.
</div>
```

So it looks like this:

```
I have something to give away for free.  Call [me|us] today and [I'll|we'll] hand deliver it to your doorstep.
```

The user then has the ability to selece "me" or "us", and "I'll" or "we'll".  Once they select one word from each group the containing  of that word has a class of "selected". But, I want to do something only when every span.togglers has an a.selected. I'm afraid I've found Javascript answers but I don't know Javascript well enough to understand how it works. How can I do this with jQuery? Or, do I HAVE to do this with Javascript?

Comment: jQuery *is* JavaScript.

Comment: show what have you tried.? and explain a bit more.!

Comment: @RocketHazmat Well yes, thanks. I'm aware that its a library based on Javascript but the syntax is different enough that  I'm still trying to find the answer with jQuery rather than with pure Javascript.

Comment: @Fletchling can you show us your current javascript? And also, javascript is usualy faster than jQuery and we tend to not use jQuery if the JS work perfectly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check if every `togglers` has an `a.selected` you can do this:

```
if ($('.togglers').length == $('.toggler.selected').length) {
    $(".toggler:not('.selected')").remove(); //removes all .toggler tags that don't have the .selected class 
}
```

(I am assuming here that your code makes sure only one `.toggler` can be `.selected` for every `.togglers`, otherwise you would have to modify the code to check every `.togglers` individually)

Comment: Brilliant! I understand why this works, too, which is what I was looking for. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

If yo want to remove element that doesn't have class 'selected', just do with jQuery:

```
$(".toggler").each(function(){
  if(!this.hasClass('selected')){
    this.remove();
  }
});
```